# conditionally include template in Jinja2

Tags: templates, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I am trying to conditionally include a specific template in my "base" template based if certain variable is defined in my host_vars. In my example, I want to check if mlag_id is defined, and if it is then I want to include "leaf_mlag_template.j2". However, if this variable is not defined, I want to fall back to include the other template "leaf_aa_template.j2". Unfortunately, it does not work as expected. If I do not define "mlag_id" variable in certain host_vars, which do not need this variable, I get an error that this variable is not defined. I am using this with Ansible to generate configuration files for Arista devices. Is there a way to conditionally include specific templates based on various parameters, such as checks if certain variables are defined, or if these variables have certain values?

[image: this is my color coded template example]

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I sounded false alarm. I noticed that I used this mlag_id variable in other templates, which I forgot about, and that was the reason I got this undefined variable error. I had to account for this other sub-templates using the same method - conditionally include them if mlag_id variable is defined.